# Как задать позицию (место) потенциального переноса (разрыва) слова, если оно не войдет в TextView по ширине?

Tags: android, android-studio, строки

Если некое слово войдет по ширине в некий TextView, то не разбивать слово.

Если нет, то слово, в заданном заранее месте (позиции) перенести на новую строку.

Например, **ABRA**[переносить только здесь]**CADABRA**

А еще лучше и с добавлением **Знака переноса**.

Или такого 'спец. формата' не существует? Все нужно писать в коде самому? )

Comment: А за что минусы, товарищи? Я действительно не знаю как решить эту проблемку! И на данном этапе она очень важная для меня!!! И очень, ОЧЕНЬ полезная!!! Зачем вы не даете людям ответить на этот вопрос? Я за этот вопрос хочу назначать премию!!!

Comment: Что за минусы без комментариев?

Comment: Я не студент! Это не студенческая работа!!! (или задание)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Есть специальный символ в Юникоде, означающий "возможное место переноса": [soft hyphen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soft_hyphen). Пример применения из Википедии (символ присутствует между всеми словами):

> Margaret­Are­You­Grieving­Over­Goldengrove­Unleaving­Leaves­Like­The­Things­Of­Man­You­With­Your­Fresh­Thoughts­Care­For­Can­You­Ah­As­The­Heart­Grows­Older­It­Will­Come­To­Such­Sights­Colder­By­And­By­Nor­Spare­A­Sigh­Though­Worlds­Of­Wanwood­Leafmeal­Lie­And­Yet­You­Will­Weep­And­Know­Why­Now­No­Matter­Child­The­Name­Sorrows­Springs­Are­The­Same­Nor­Mouth­Had­No­Nor­Mind­Expressed­What­Heart­Heard­Of­Ghost­Guessed­It­Is­The­Blight­Man­Was­Born­For­It­Is­Margaret­You­Mourn­For

Насколько мне известно, в Андроиде он работает корректно.

Comment: Огромное Спасибо! Друг!!! )

Answer (score 1):

А что тут, собственно, делать? Нужно просто посчитать, сколько примерно символов умещается в одну строчку. И использовать примерно такую функцию (псевдокод):

```
public static string computeTextTranslate(string input, int line_size) {
    bool next_line = false;
    int used_size = 0;
    string result = "";
    for(int i = 0; i<input.Length;; i++)
    {
        if(used_size-1==line_size) {
            next_line=true;
        }
        if(next_line && input[i] == 'сюда символ переноса') {
            result += "-\n"
            string_size++;
            next_line = false;
        } else {
            result+=input[i]; 
            used_size++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: «Примерно» это совсем не круто. После слова вида «iiiiii» будет много пустого места, а строка вида «WWWWWW» может и не влезть

Comment: @Andreymal, да, вы правы. Но и такую проблему можно обойти. Можно в исходную строку вставлять символы, которые будут при обработки автоматически убираться, но увеличивать used_size. Тем самым, поставив после "W" несколько таких невидимых символов можно будет доказать программе, что "W" - не один символ, а, скажем, 3